How to run 'npm-create-vite@latest' command successfully in VS Code terminal?
I've tried to create vite@latest in Visual Studio Code terminal plugin. Terminal says this error:
npm : File C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.ps1 cannot be loaded. The file C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.ps1 is not digitally signed. You cannot 
run this script on the current system. For more information about running scripts and setting execution policy, see 
about_Execution_Policies at https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
At line:1 char:1
+ npm create vital@latest
+ ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess


Please follow this instruction "Unblock a script to run it without changing the execution policy" https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/set-executionpolicy?view=powershell-7.4

run this command in terminal
Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope Process -ExecutionPolicy Bypass
check the solution here

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

PowerShell will not allow you to execute scripts at will. You can change that behavior by running this in an elevated terminal (run as admin):
Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted

The documentation is here.
-Edit-
Adding the -Scope Process flag is generally encouraged.

@Tim-R-Jensen,  already installed my , how can I solve the error?
